# Repeat a table header for media print using table-header-group

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a table-based header to repeat each time a page-break occurs. My table-header repeat correclty if it does not contain any table inside.

I'm using this code :

```
<table class="report-container">
   <thead class="report-header">
      <tr>
         <th class="report-header-cell">
           ...
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="report-footer">
       <tr>
          <td class="report-footer-cell">
           ...
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class="report-content">
       <tr>
          <td class="report-content-cell">
            ...
          </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

And this CSS :

```
table.report-container {
    page-break-after:always;
}
thead.report-header {
    display:table-header-group;
}
tfoot.report-footer {
    display:table-footer-group;
}
```

I can put anything I want in my th.report-header-cell, this will work. But not if I put another table inside. Is there a trick to get ride of this kind of problem ?

I tried to change the display of my tables, not working also.

I'm running on Google Chrome & my projet use Bootstrap 4 tables, but notice that basic tables will not work also.

**EDIT** : Here is how I put a table in my th.report-header-cell :

```
<table class="report-container">
    <thead class="report-header">
        <tr>
            <th class="report-header-cell">
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%;">
                                ...
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:50%;">
                                ...
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This example will not print my header in each page, but only on the first one. The footer will continue to work and will be printed on each page.

Comment: Please show us how you `put another table inside`

Comment: I just edited my code. :)